# Flutter CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: api, https, flutter

I'm trying to do POST data from flutter through the API. When implemented via `http`, everything went well.
But when using the `HTTPS` protocol, a `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` error message appears.
I use Laravel with nginx.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Can you post us some code so that people can eventually see where the error is? Thanks.

Comment: this is my codevar uri = Uri.parse(globals.apiUrl);
      var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
      request.fields['android_token'] = '$idToken';
      request.fields['nik'] = loginNikController.text;
      request.fields['password'] = loginPasswordController.text;
      var response = await request.send();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) { . . . . i'm use this package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http